# How to close instance created by adding doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-addins

I am inserting a word document into a word document by `doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject`.

`doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(System.Type.Missing, filename, true, false, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, range)`;

It inserts the embedded document,but after closing the main word file, `WINWORD.EXE` process still running. How to solve this problem. can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bielive the issue is related to not releasing uinderlying COM objects in the code. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release a Word object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. See [Office application does not quit after automation from Visual Studio .NET client](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317109/) for more information about the issue.